# iOS - Call method when any app starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I want to call an action which will get called **every time any app start**.

Example:

Showing a modal with app name saying **Welcome to Twitter.**

Comment: iOS does not let you annoy your users that way and for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can add that action in this method of app delegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

         perfornAction()

         return true
    }
```

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will not get called every time. It will get called for first time or when we open app after terminating it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods in which you can write your code.

1. `applicationWillEnterForeground`: Gets called when you app comes into picture after INACTIVE or TERMINATED state
2. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: Gets called when app gets called for first time. Also this method will get called when app is in terminated state and you open the app.

So if you want to perform it every time when app opens, prefer `applicationWillEnterForeground`. And for first time user call same method in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with some flag value(Set it to true when your code runs successfully) so that your method will not get called twice.